# On a roll of 5, can the room be searched?

Tags: solo, four-against-darkness

In Four Against Darkness, 'You may search an empty room...' (pg. 31), and on a roll of 5 on the Room Contents Table, the result is 'Empty. Roll on the **Special Feature** table.' Given the full stop, does this count as an empty, searchable room?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can search the room on a 5. Check out the “Guide to Dungeon and Room Building Tables” flowchart on page 83 (v4.0)

Comment: Nice, I completely overlooked that flowchart.  Thanks!